# I would like to open my RDS database in another Availability Zone, which I can write into

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-rds

PS, I am very new to AWS... pretty much an absolute beginner.

Okay,
I am having trouble creating an RDS database in a different Availability Zone.

My Availability Zone is Sydney, because I'm in New Zealand but my app is running in India only so I must create an RDS database in Mumbai region so that the speed can increase.

But I can't do that because once I create this database, I can't connect into it. It gives me an connection timeout error.

Does anybody know how to fix this??

Thanks,
Arnav.

Comment: You can try adding `--connect-timeout=` to increase. Which flavour of RDS are you using? We've got many Aurora clusters in Sydney that I access from the UK but we use EC2 hop in the same region than direct access.

Comment: To be able to "fix" that, you have to provide ALL settings of your RDS, VPC, security groups, subnets, etc. You haven't provided any relevant information that can be use to fix that.

Comment: @Marcin I have only created the rds db and do not have any clue about how to make VPC's and security groups. If you could show me from start to finish how you would implement something like this, that would help alot :)

Comment: @Prav I am using MySQL flavour, where can I edit the connect-timeout?

Comment: @Prav I am also connecting directly into my rds instance

Comment: FYI this is probably better suited for ServerFault, not Stack Overflow - it's infra-related, not programming-related.